# add onclick programmatically failed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#target a').attr("onClick=", link);
```

for some reason I have to do this one, but it says `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'onclick=' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: what is `link`? is it a function?

Comment: Why not just ` $('#target a').on('click', link) ;`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#target a').attr("onClick", link);
```

This is what you're looking for.

Though you could use:

```
$('#target a').on('click', link);
```

Please note that **link** should be a function and not just a url.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need attribute editing. You just need to set 'click' event handler.

```
$('#target a').click(link);
```

where link is a handling function.